# Is there a way to stop the file tabs from repositioning when saving in spyder?

Tags: spyder

When working with multiple files, I have them visible in tabs, where I go back and forth between them. But every time I save, it repositioned the tab for file that was just saved to the right. But often there are files I still want to work with the the right of it. So I have to use the small arrow keys to get back to those files. Is there a way to keep all the file tabs in place when saving?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a [known bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5459), we know it's very frustrating and we're working to solve it. I hope it should be fixed in a couple of months.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba ok good to know I'm not the only one who finds this frustrating lol. An option to make the arrow keys bigger would be cool also imho. Thanks

Comment: Agreed and that's fixed in Spyder 5, but only if you're using our [Windows or macOS installers](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases), or Conda-forge. Unfortunately, that's something we can't fix in Anaconda.

Comment: Ok I use anaconda, oh well.